# Java Script Alternate Concatenation Techniques

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Maybe my question is noobish but I could not find any answer on the Internet.

```
 <script>

    var1 = "";
    someFuntion();
    var2 = "";

</script>
```

Let say I have a script like this and I can change var1 value by entering string.
When I enter this payload "/alert(9)/"  to var1 script becomes like this:

```
<script>

    asd = ""/alert(9)/"";
    qwe();
    zxc = "";

</script>
```

and when browser renders html it executes alert() and popup cames. Also with different payloads like "|alert(9)|", "!=alert(9)!=" , ";alert(9);//   browser still creates popup.

Can someone explain how is that possible, what is the meaning of script becomes after injecting payloads which I have shown?

Please describe me the anatomy of the changed script i.e what asd variable becomes, what is the meaning of concatenations right and left of alert() mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
asd = ""/alert(9)/"";
```

means take an empty string, divide it by whatever `alert(9)` returns, divide this by an empty string and assign the result to `asd`. Since JS is weakly-typed, it's no problem to perform division on strings - it just returns `NaN`. As a side effect, you see the alert.

Injecting user input in your scripts is a terrible idea, but if you must, you should escape strings to avoid hacks like this. The safest method is to run them through `JSON.stringify`:

```
userInput = '"/alert(9)/"'
safeExpr = JSON.stringify(userInput)
someJSCode = "var asd = " + safeExpr
```

which gives you

```
var asd="\"/alert(9)/\""
```